# 16-тиричное считывание из файла C++

Tags: c++, fstream

Излазил вдоль и поперек форум(скорее всего чего-то не заметил).

Подскажите синтаксис считывания шестнадцатеричного числа из текстового файла в переменную типа `int`(или может есть специальные типы данных для 16-ти ричных чисел?). Нашел инструкцию `base_ios::hex`, но так и не понял ее синтаксис.

Например есть какой-то файл *text.txt*, и в нем есть число `A1B7`, хотелось бы считать его (хотелось бы еще сильнее побитово) в переменную типа `int` с помощью класса fstream(или может есть какие-нибудь аналоги, сишный `FILE` - тоже ок, но хотелось бы без него).

Буду сильно признателен за небольшое разжевывание синтаксиса.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Пусть есть файл:

```
std::ifstream file("foo.txt");
```

Переключаем в 16-ричный режим:

```
file >> std::hex;
```

Считываем число:

```
int x;
file >> x;
```

Возвращаем в режим по умолчанию:

```
file >> std::setbase(0);
```

---

Это можно делать и в одну строчку:

```
int x;
file >> std::hex >> x >> std::setbase(0);
```

Comment: разве возвращение в режим по умолчанию, не произойдет по умолчанию?..

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Не-а http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/49cc0e41ecbbf634